# Filter array by tag Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently working with vuejs and vuex. Here is my issue :

I have a store with all the data

```
state: {
  articles: [{
    title: "Article 1",
    id: 1,
    tag: "Tutorial"
  }, {
    title: "Article 2",
    id: 2,
    description: "Article 2",
    tag: "Review"
  }
 }]
```

}

On the homepage, I want to display all kind of articles. On the tutorial page I only want to display articles with tag "tutorial", etc...

I'm using `vue-router`. I'm working with a computed property and a `v-for` so I can loop in the articles.

```
computed: {
        articles() {
            if (this.$route.meta.title == 'Tutorial') {
                return this.$store.state.articles.tag == 'Tutorial'
            }
            if (this.$route.meta.title == 'Review') {
                return this.$store.state.articles.tag == 'Review'
            }
            else if (this.$route.meta.title == 'Home') {
                return this.$store.state.articles
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that `return this.$store.state.articles.tag == 'Tutorial'` can't work, I'm looking for a way to code it correctly but I'm stuck!

Also, if you have a completely different and better way to do it, feel free to tell me!

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: why don't/can't you use a simple `filter` method of arrays?

Comment: Oh my god. I'm stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody mentioned you will need to use filter but as a pattern you should structure it with  `vuex getters`
when you access properties from vuex state do not to access them directly but the correct thing is to use getters

Vuex store e.x.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    articles: [
   {
    title: "Article 1",
    id: 1,
    tag: "Tutorial"
  }, 
  {
    title: "Article 2",
    id: 2,
    description: "Article 2",
    tag: "Review"
  }

 ]
},
getters: {
   allArticles: state => {
     return state.articles
   },
   tutorialArticles: state=>{
      return state.articles.filter(article=>articles.tag=='Tutorial')
   },
   reviewArticles: state=>{
    return state.articles.filter(articles=>articles.tag=='Review')
  }
}
 })
 //end of vuex store
```

Then in your "all articles" component you use

```
 computed:{
    articles(){
      return this.$store.getters.allArticles;
    }
 }
```

Then in your tutorial articles component you use

```
 computed:{
    articles(){
       return this.$store.getters.tutorialArticles;
    }
 }
```

This is very important because if you need to change the code for the filter method you do it in one place and thats the purpose of using Vuex

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is using [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj =  {state: {
    articles: [{
      title: "Article 1",
      id: 1,
      tag: "Tutorial"
    }, {
      title: "Article 2",
      id: 2,
      description: "Article 2",
      tag: "Review"
    }
   ]}}

var filtered = obj.state.articles.filter(o=>o.tag == "Tutorial");

console.log(filtered)
```